# Tool or IconSet to visualize network topology

Tags: graph, topology

I'm looking for a tool or IconSet do create a picture of a network topology. The network doesn't exist, so I don't need a tool that scans a network and creates a picture of that network.

It would be nice if things like server(database, web, file), switches and firewall were included.

A free tool or iconset would be great because I probably only need it one time, but if there aren't any good free options I will pay if it is not a couple hundred dollar or euros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [WERESC CADE](http://www.weresc.com/network.php) for this sort of thing - AFAIK it's still free. The website's not great but the tool itself is pretty good. If that doesn't do the job try Googling for 'Network diagramming tools'

Answer (score 2):

Dia (cross platform/open source) from memory has most of those icons your looking for if I remember correctly,